# In R and ddply, is it possible to avoid enumerating all columns I need when using ddply?

Tags: r, plyr

Other posts suggested that ddply is a good workhorse.
I am trying to learn xxply functions and I can not solve this problem.

This is my

```
library(ggplot2)
(df= tips[1:5,])
             total_bill                   tip    sex smoker day   time size
1 16.989999999999998437 1.0100000000000000089 Female     No Sun Dinner    2
2 10.339999999999999858 1.6599999999999999201   Male     No Sun Dinner    3
3 21.010000000000001563 3.5000000000000000000   Male     No Sun Dinner    3
4 23.679999999999999716 3.3100000000000000533   Male     No Sun Dinner    2
5 24.589999999999999858 3.6099999999999998757 Female     No Sun Dinner    4
```

and I need to something like this

```
ddply(df
       ,.(<do I have to enumerate all columns I need to operate on here?)>
       , function(x) {if size>=3 return(size) else return(total_bill+tip)
     )
```

(the example is a fake problem (does not make real life sense) and only demonstrates my problem with larger data)

1. I could not get the ddply code right reading just help files. Any advise appreciated. Or even great ddply tutorial?
2. I like that with ddply I can just pass my dataframe as input, but in the second argument, it is not nice that I am forced to enumerate all columns that I need later. Is there a way to pass the whole row (all columns)?
3. I like defining the function on the fly, but I am not sure how to make my pseudocode correct in R (my last argument).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your code, it doesn't look like you need to use plyr here at all. It seems to me you are calculating a new variable for each row of the data.frame. If that's the case, then just use some base R functions:

```
dat <- transform(dat, newval = ifelse(size >= 3, size, total_bill + tip))

  total_bill  tip    sex smoker day   time size newval
1      16.99 1.01 Female     No Sun Dinner    2  18.00
2      10.34 1.66   Male     No Sun Dinner    3   3.00
3      21.01 3.50   Male     No Sun Dinner    3   3.00
4      23.68 3.31   Male     No Sun Dinner    2  26.99
5      24.59 3.61 Female     No Sun Dinner    4   4.00
```

Sorry if I misunderstood what you are doing. If you do in fact need to pass the entire row of a data.frame into plyr with no grouping variable, perhaps you can treat it as an array with margin = 1? i.e `adply(dat, 1, ...)`

Great introduction of plyr here: www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/paper

Comment: the transform trick is very nice and new to me. I saw that paper. thx

Answer (score 3):

The second argument is the "splitting" variable.  so in your sample data set, if you're looking to see the difference in spending habits between the sexes you would supply `.(sex)` or if you want all possibilities of your categorical variables, yes you would have to supply them all `.(sex, smoker, day, time)`.

On a separate note, when using `ddply` your function should take a `data.frame` and return a `data.frame`.  Currently It returns a vector.  Also, `if` is not vectorized, you should use `ifelse`.

```
ddply(df, .(sex), function(x) {
      x$new.var <- ifelse(x$size >= 3, x$size, x$total_bill + x$tip)
      return(x)
})
```

if you don't specify the return value, `R` will return the last thing calculated which is a vector.

My only other suggestion is to keep playing with `plyr`.  Eventually it will click and you'll love it!

Comment: I think you can operate on all columns by using `.var = names(df)`.

Comment: I need to learn *apply techniques and decided to go with plyr

Comment: @Justin Uh... I don't really know what I was thinking there.  Let's pretend I meant to say this: If you wanted to operate on all of the factors in a data.frame, you can do it like this: `ddply(df, .var = names(df)[names(df)[t(colwise(is.factor)(df))]], .fun = ...)`  Basically, it's sometimes easier to subset `names(df)` to what you need than to explicitly spell out each variable name.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if this is still useful. Whilst I am not sure whether this is adequate I am used to solve tasks similar to yours as follows:

```
ddply(df
       , as.quoted(colnames(df))
       , function(x) {if size>=3 return(size) else return(total_bill+tip)
     )
```